# Unable to get data from edittext after pasting the data from clipboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

so i have this scenario where the data from clipboard is getting shown even if the data im storing in the variable is from the editText.getText()

this is the string i pasted
"https://www.threads.net/@thetatvaindia/post/Cul0ODALRWq"

after pasting the data i edited and make this

[www.threads.net/@thetatvaindia/post/Cul0ODALRWq](http://www.threads.net/@thetatvaindia/post/Cul0ODALRWq)

but still in the toast its shwoing me the previous one

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textField);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        downloadBtnCard = findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
        textStatus = findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        final String[] threadLink = new String[1];

        String editTextValue = editText.getText().toString();
        threadLink[0] = editTextValue;
        textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                if (clipboard != null && clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                    CharSequence clipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        editText.setText(clipData);
                        String editTextValue = editText.getText().toString();
                        threadLink[0] = editTextValue;
                    }
                }
                textInputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cancel_24);
                textInputLayout.setEndIconContentDescription(getString(R.string.canel_icon));
            }
        });

 downloadBtnCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = threadLink[0];
                linkValidation(url);

            }
        });


}
 public void linkValidation(String url) {
        textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.white));
        textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.validating_link));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Regex pattern for profile link
        Pattern profileLinkPattern = Pattern.compile("^https://www.threads.net/@[^/]+$");
        // Regex pattern for post link
//                Pattern postWithNoHttps = Pattern.compile("^(?!https:\\/\\/)(.*(?:www\\.)?threads\\.net).*");
//                Matcher postWithNoHTTPS_Matcher = postWithNoHttps.matcher(url);
        Matcher profileMatcher = profileLinkPattern.matcher(url);
        if(url.startsWith("https://www.threads.net")||url.startsWith("https://threads.net")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (profileMatcher.matches()) {
                textStatus.setText(null);
                textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.profile_link));
            } else if (url.contains("/post/") || url.contains("threads.net/t/")) {
                textStatus.setText(null);
                textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.post_link));
            } else {
                textStatus.setText(null);
                textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadlink_invaliddataurl));
            }
        }else if (((!url.startsWith("https://"))&&(url.contains("www.threads.net"))) || ((!url.startsWith("https://")&&(url.contains("https://threads.net")))))
        {
            textStatus.setText(null);
            textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadLink_NoHttps));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invailed Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textStatus.setText(null);
            textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadLink_False));
        }

    }
```

Comment: After adding data to edit text, do you hit download button to process the input? If that the case you should get input in download button's on click listener.

Comment: What message are you seeing on Toast, there are lots of cases on your code? What did you copy/paste and to what it changed to is unclear from your question, wrap it `as code` with tick character ` Why `setEndIconDrawable` is inside onClickListener?

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya comment solved the issue